# Demostrar calculadora em Pilha

Tags: c#

Estou com um problema aqui e preciso de uma ajuda, tenho que fazer um trabalho para faculdade, e uma calculadora, até ai tudo bem já ate tenho feito a calculadora, só que o problema e o seguinte, preciso demonstrar os números em pilha, alguém sabe como fazer isso, pelo que entendi pilha e último que entra e o primeiro que sai, só que não faço ideia de como fazer isso no meu código.

Segue o código da calculadora.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string operador;
        int a = 0;
        bool validar = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void btnNumerador_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button bt = (Button)sender;
        txt_valor.Text = txt_valor.Text + bt.Text;
    }

    private void btn_cancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_valor.Text = "";
        lbl_numero.Text = "";
        a = 0;
    }

    private void btn_somar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (validar == true)
        {
            a = a + Convert.ToInt32(txt_valor.Text);
            lbl_numero.Text = Convert.ToString(a) + "+";
            txt_valor.Text = "";
            operador = "+";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_numero.Text = txt_valor.Text + btn_somar.Text;
            a = Convert.ToInt32(txt_valor.Text);
            txt_valor.Text = "";
            operador = "+";
            validar = true;
        }
    }

    private void btn_subtrair_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (validar == true)
        {
            a = a - Convert.ToInt32(txt_valor.Text);
            lbl_numero.Text = Convert.ToString(a) + "-";
            txt_valor.Text = "";
            operador = "-";
            validar = false;
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_numero.Text = txt_valor.Text + btn_subtrair.Text;
            a = Convert.ToInt32(txt_valor.Text);
            txt_valor.Text = "";
            operador = "-";
        }
    }

    private void btn_multiplicar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (validar == true)
        {
            a = a * Convert.ToInt32(txt_valor.Text);
            lbl_numero.Text = Convert.ToString(a) + "*";
            txt_valor.Text = "";
            operador = "*";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_numero.Text = txt_valor.Text + btn_multiplicar.Text;
            a = Convert.ToInt32(txt_valor.Text);
            txt_valor.Text = "";
            operador = "*";
            validar = true;
        }
    }

    private void btn_dividir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (validar == true)
        {
            a = a / Convert.ToInt32(txt_valor.Text);
            lbl_numero.Text = Convert.ToString(a) + "/";
            txt_valor.Text = "";
            operador = "/";
            validar = false;

        }
        else
        {
            lbl_numero.Text = txt_valor.Text + btn_dividir.Text;
            a = Convert.ToInt32(txt_valor.Text);
            txt_valor.Text = "";
            operador = "/";
        }
    }

    private void btn_igual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (operador == "+")
        {
            lbl_numero.Text = lbl_numero.Text + txt_valor.Text + "=";
            txt_valor.Text = Convert.ToString(a + Convert.ToInt32(txt_valor.Text));
        }
        else if (operador == "-")
        {
            lbl_numero.Text = lbl_numero.Text + txt_valor.Text + "=";
            txt_valor.Text = Convert.ToString(a - Convert.ToInt32(txt_valor.Text));
        }
        else if (operador == "*")
        {
            lbl_numero.Text = lbl_numero.Text + txt_valor.Text + "=";
            txt_valor.Text = Convert.ToString(a * Convert.ToInt32(txt_valor.Text));
        }
        else if (operador == "/")
        {
            lbl_numero.Text = lbl_numero.Text + txt_valor.Text + "=";
            txt_valor.Text = Convert.ToString(a / Convert.ToInt32(txt_valor.Text));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "demonstrar os números em pilha" explique melhor essa afirmação. Quer implementar os cálculos de uma calculadora com base numa estrutura de dados do tipo Pilha ? mostrar o resultado visualmente como se fosse uma pilha ?

Comment: Isso mesmo Isac, preciso demonstrar os calculos como base de estrutura em pilha isso mesmo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É comum em calculadoras utilizar pilhas, existem inclusive calculadoras que trabalham com [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), mas em seu caso acredito que não seja necessário RPN. O que você deve fazer para trabalhar com pilha é lembrar que, pilha nada mais é do que uma **Lista Encadeada** com a regra LIFO (ultimo que entra, primeiro que sai). A partir daí, você terá que alterar todo seu código, infelizmente, para trabalhar com sua pilha.

EDIT: Fiz um pseudo código aqui para você tomar como base:

```
public class Calculadora
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> Lista = new List<int>();
    Lista.Add(4);
    Lista.Add(5);

    Console.WriteLine(Somar(Lista));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static int Somar (List<int> Lista)
{
    if (Lista != null && Lista.Count >= 2)
    {
        int valorA = Lista.FirstOrDefault();
        Lista.Remove(Lista.FirstOrDefault());
        int valorB = Lista.FirstOrDefault();
        Lista.Remove(Lista.FirstOrDefault());

        return valorA + valorB;
    }
    return 0;
}

public static int Desempilha (List<int> Lista)
{
    if (Lista == null)
        return 0;

    int retorno = Lista.FirstOrDefault();
    Lista.Remove(Lista.FirstOrDefault());
    return retorno;
}

public static List<int> Empilha (List<int> Lista, int valor)
{
    if (Lista == null)
    {
        Lista = new List<int>();
        Lista.Add(valor);
    }
    else
        Lista.Add(valor);

    return Lista;
    }
}
```

Utilizei a própria List pois você está trabalhando com c#

Comment: Inclusive, já que está trabalhando com Forms, que tal fazer uma perfumaria pro professor? mostrar a sua pilha em tempo real na tela.

Comment: Acredito que pilha se refira a estrutura LIFO (Last in, First Out). Uma fila é mais apropriado ao FIFO.

Comment: @Vinícius Realmente, me confundi, já ajustei, obrigado!

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo seu exemplo, me ajudou muito aqui vlw.

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro fico feliz, se der pra avaliar a resposta por favor :D

Comment: +1 pela explicação e pelo código bem exemplificado.

Comment: porque não usar `Stack<>` ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections.stack(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RovannLinhalis é uma boa também, mas particularmente eu não conheço.

Comment: é só a classe pilha, da mesma forma que a lista... só usar `Push` e `Pop` tudo pronto rs

Comment: @RovannLinhalis legal, é interessante.. mas por ser um trabalho acadêmico, e o principal objetivo é aprender, acho que utilizar coisas prontas nem sempre são a melhor opção, mas de qualquer maneira, é bom saber que existe pronto, obrigado :D

Comment: sim, pensei nessa possibilidade... inclusive na faculdade implementei as lista, fila e pilha, mas como foi usado a List<>, que já está pronta, é quase equivalente usar a Stack<> rsrs. Ps. É só um comentário, vlw